# Send an response 200 from a Spring boot controller for asyncronus processing

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a scenario:
I've a controller.
My controller is calling the service class.Service class will fetch all the records from data base and post it to kafka.But I don't want my client  who is calling the api to wait till the entire data is posted to kafka. I want it to do in a asynchronous way. Client's work is  only to invoke the api that's all. We will immediately send 200 response code.

In back end the data fetching from DB and processing to kafka will happen.
Can you please suggest how this can be done.

```
public class SampleController {

    private  SampleService sampleService;
        @PostMapping("/")
        public String handleAsyncResponse(@RequestBody Requestbean bean) {
        sampleService.posttokafka(bean);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You can try with Webflux. Its reactive pattern can achieve what you are looking for, also it will help in efficient data retrieval and posting to Kafka.

Comment: Another possibility would be to use Spring's `@Async` annotation. See, for example, [this article over at baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async).

Comment: hi @Nick any example code to refer for above case?I  have never worked on webflux. So,not aware of it

Comment: @Debo I don't have any quick example but this article will help you https://spring.io/guides/gs/reactive-rest-service/. On the other hand as Turing85 suggested `@Async` will also be option.

Comment: Note that the correct response is 202 rather than 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it via @Async way as follows, first define a bean:

```
@Configuration
public class SThreads {
    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor concurrentTasks() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(4);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(4);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("default_task_executor_thread");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

And the annotate the task with `@Async("concurrentTasks")`

```
@Async("concurrentTasks")
public static void myAsyncTask() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    ....
}
```

Then you can call the myAsyncTask and it will not block the caller.

Comment: thank u sooooo much @Nick    :-)..let me try this code ...i can call this myAsyncTask() from my controller ,correct?

Comment: HI @Nick another requirement..now myAsyncTask will be executed by 4 parallel threads.Now myAsyncTask what it is doing in my case is reading data from database using jpa repository and putting it to kafka. There are 16 k records.When the entire 16 records are done,i have no notify to client via email. publishtokafka() is doing that..How can I handle this?how will know that  myAsyncTask()  has completed its execution so that i can notify client

Comment: @Debo nope, your task will be executed in one of the threads. To execute 4 parallel tasks you will have to create separate Runnable instances. For other topics - please ask followup questions as separate SO questions

Comment: @Debo myAsyncTask will run as one instance and it won't be async in its own block unless its code says so. You can have some state in the main thread or elsewhere which you can update once your myAsyncTask finishes its part.